# max-height and max-width unexpected behavior in FF and IE11 under flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent with `flexbox` and an image in that element with `max-height` and `max-width`. This displays fine in Chrome (ofc), but on Firefox the image is displayed with `height:100%` and `width:100%` while in IE it's displayed with `width` way over `100%`.

I've created an example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/arzLw).

HTML:

```
<div id='flex'>
  <img src='https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#flex {
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;    
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  display:block;
  display: -webkit-flex;    
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

How do I display the image with `max-height` and `max-width` "normally" (`display:block;` on `#flex`)? I need `display:flex` so I can display the image in the center (vertically). If you change `display` to `block` on codepen you'll see how the image should look like.

How it looks like in Chrome (correct):

[image]

How it looks like in Firefox:

[image]

How it looks like in IE11:

[image]

Comment: try using `%` instead of `px` in width and height of `#flex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could unfortunately not find any solution to this so I had to use `display:table`/`display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` instead.

Working copy available at [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kaepo).

Markup

```
<div id='flex'>
  <div>
     <div>
        <img src='https://www.google.se/images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#flex {
  display:table;
  background:purple;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

#flex > div { 
  display:table-cell;
  height: inherit; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:inherit; 
}
#flex > div > div {
  width:inherit;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: there is a solution, nowadays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489798/keep-image-ratio-using-max-width-and-max-height-in-ie-11/43227016#43227016

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind adding some markup, enclose the image inside another container which it can earn its parent height and width from instead of the flex container. This should solve the problem in Firefox, I cannot test it in Internet Explorer 11 for you though. You might have to add additional width/height styling to the new container in order for it to work in all browsers.